# How to check if the file is used by another thread Java with Socket?

Tags: java

I want to implement an application that will allow me to transfer files between client and server.

The client requests a file, if the file is not used by another client the server will send the file, otherwise the thread id will be saved in the queue.

My question is how i can check if the file is used by another thread ?

here is my code :
ClientFile.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ClientFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 43333);
        System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

        //Read and write on socket.
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        //Read from console.
        BufferedReader bfIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = null;
        while ((bufferedReader.read()) != '~') {
           System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }


        //DemanderF
        System.out.print("Enter File Id: ");
        int response = bfIn.read();
        printWriter.println(response);

        //From ASCII TO INT.
        int fileId = Character.getNumericValue(response);
        //System.out.println("blabla " + fileId);

        /*-----------------Receive F------------------*/
        //The inputStream class will capture the streams which has been sent by the server.
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        receiveF(inputStream, fileId);
        /*---------------------------------------*/


        bufferedReader.close();
        printWriter.close();
        socket.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //System.out.println("IOException Client ---> "+ e.getStackTrace());
        }

    }


    public static void receiveF(InputStream inputStream, int fileId)
    {
        try {
        //Create File inside desired folder
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\newFile.txt");

        //byte array (size of the file).
        byte []b = new byte[2002];

        //Read a Stream.
        inputStream.read(b, 0, b.length);
        //Write the whole content into file.
        fileOutputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);

        fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

ServerFile.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.rmi.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ServerFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //create ServerSocket on port 43333.
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(43333);
            while(true)
            {
            System.out.println("Running...");

            //accept incoming Client request.
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("\nClient connected");
            //System.out.println("Id Client : " +clientSocket);

            System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

            Thread t = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);

            t.start();
            }
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException ---> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("IOException ---> " + e1.getMessage());
        }
    }

    static class ClientHandler extends Thread {

        Socket clientSocket;

        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {               
                //Read and write on socket.
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()), true);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                //Send File list.
                String directoryName = "C:\\Users\\AZZEM\\Documents\\Master 1\\Système répartis\\Files";
                File file = new File(directoryName);
                File fileList[] = file.listFiles();

                int c = 0;

                for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
                {

                    if(fileList[i].canRead() && (fileList[i].toString().endsWith(".txt")))
                    {
                        c++;
                    }

                    //System.out.println("File list : " + fileList[i].getName() + " and Size = " + fileList[i].length() + "bytes"); 
                }

                printWriter.println(" " + c + " .txt files, listed A-Z \n");

                for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
                {
                    printWriter.println(" " + fileList[i].getName() + " and Size = " + fileList[i].length() + "bytes");
                }       

                printWriter.println("~");

                String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
                int fid = Integer.parseInt(response);
                //From ASCII TO INT.
                int fileId = Character.getNumericValue(fid);

                int threadId = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                System.out.println("My id is " + threadId + " and I want the file "+ fileId);

                boolean isExist = false;

                if(fileId >=0  && fileId<=fileList.length)
                {
                    isExist = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isExist = false;
                    System.out.println("File not exist");
                }

                if(isExist == true)
                {

                    System.out.println("The file " + fileId + "is used");
                    /*--------------------------Send File to Client------------------------------*/
                    File fileToSend = new File(fileList[fileId].getAbsolutePath());
                    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileToSend);

                    //Read File.
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileList[fileId].getAbsolutePath());

                    //Byte Array is used to include the size of the array.
                    byte[]b = new byte[2002];

                    //The read method --> Start reading the file from 0 to the end of the file (length).
                    //And store it in new variable which is b.
                    fileInputStream.read(b, 0, b.length);

                    //Convert file into streams.
                    OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

                    //Send the whole file using outputStream class.
                    System.out.println("Sending File...");
                    outputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);
                    System.out.println("File Transferred"); 
                    fileInputStream.close();
                /*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                }


                bufferedReader.close();
                printWriter.close();
                clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in use"?

Comment: It means that the client reads or writes to the file,
when the file is sent to the client cannot be used by another client until the client sends "release"

Comment: You have already told the solution.  The server won't know that after a client get a file, whether the client is using it or not.  It is all about your communication between client and server, that client need to tell server that they have finished using the file and release it

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how does the server queue the other thread if the file is used ?
Thank you for your help. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Why do you need to queue it? Just reply to client that the file is in use, and let your client decide if they want to acquire it again. If you really want to wait within the request, learn things like synchronisation,  wait/notify , or file lock, etc. Easiest way is to acquire a lock (or by synchronized) have a little component to return a lock to represent a file (same file needs to be same object). Multiple thread trying to acquire same object will be automatically “queued up “